# Tracing Recursive Function

Tags: c, recursion

The following program's output looks like this:
n = 2 n = 1 n = 0 n = -1 n = 0 n = 1

I can follow through the program to the point where it prints out n = -1, but why does it go back up and prints n = 0 and n = 1 at the end?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void countdown (int n)
{

    printf("n = %d\t", n);

    n--;

    if (n >= 0)

    {

            countdown(n);

    }

    printf("n = %d\t", n);

}


int main()

{

    countdown(2);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: answer this question first: why does it print n=-1?

Answer (score 1):

There are two `printf`s in the function, the last 3 `printfs` (`n = -1 n = 0 n = 1`) in your sequence
are printed by the second `printf` call, that's why it goes up again. You are forgetting about that one. When
the recursion ends, the function returns back to the previous level and continues
from there.

Eventually `n--` is executed for `n==0`, `n` becomes negative, `n >= 0` is evaluates
to false and `countdown(n)` is not executed any more. That's the terminal case.
That means that the function stops calling itself and continues and to the next statement which is the second
`printf`, which will print `n = -1`.

Then the function returns and the last and continues, which executes the second
`printf` and you get `n = 0`. Then the function ends and returns to the first
level, where the second `printf` is executed and you get `n = 1`. Then the
function returns back to `main`.

If you change the `printf`s a little bit in your recursion, you'll see
immediately why you get the output. Try this:

```
void countdown (int n)
{

    printf("[1] n = %d\n", n);

    n--;

    if (n >= 0)

    {

            countdown(n);

    }

    printf("[2] n = %d\n", n);

}
```

Now the output will be

```
[1] n = 2
[1] n = 1
[1] n = 0
[2] n = -1
[2] n = 0
[2] n = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two printf statements being executed per call of the countdown function (one before and one after the recursive countdown() call).

It's a little hard to illustrate here, but let's look at how your countdown() function is being executed, and remember that in this case, the variable n is local to its associated function scope meaning that each occurrence of "n" within each countdown() function call is independent of the other.

```
countdown(2) <- spawns a new execution scope; let's call it S0
  => prints "n=2"
  => sets n=1 in scope S0
  => calls countdown(1) <- spawns a new execution scope; let's call it S1
    ----Inside S1----
    => prints "n=1"
    => sets n=0 in scope S1
    => calls countdown(0) <- spawns a new execution scope; let's call it S2
      ----Inside S2----
      => prints "n=0"
      => sets n=-1 in scope S2
      => if condition fails
      => prints "n=-1"
      => returns execution to scope S1
    => prints "n=0" (which is the value "n" has in scope S1)
    => returns execution to scope S0
  => prints "n=1" (which is the value "n" has in scope S0)
  => execution returns to main() function and program terminates
```

Answer (score 0):

For `n = 1` and `n = 0`, stack position is saved to go ahead where the function is stopped temporarily. After `n=-1` case, the stack goes back from the saved positon. That's why you got `n = 0` and `n = 1` again with reversed-ordered. I recommend you to look at `stack` structure thereby grasping recursion logic.